ASP.NET Core | How are controllers detected and routed in an ASP.NET Core web application?
Coming from writing API endpoints (albeit relatively simple ones) in Flask and Express.JS, I'm having trouble understanding how routes and controllers are initialized in an ASP.NET application. It seems that even though the files and classes exists, they aren't referenced anywhere when configuring/initializing the application.
So for example, there exists a file SomeController.cs in Controllers/ which looks roughly like this:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase {
 // ... dependencies, routes, functions, etc, go here ...
}

Then, in ConfigureServices() services like health checking is added:
services.AddControllers(); // <- I suspect this is how the controller is added...
services.AddHealthChecks();
// ... etc ...

And finally, in Configure() middleware is set up:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
  endpoints.MapControllers(); // <- Or maybe its added here?
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

What confuses me is that nowhere in the codebase is the class SomeController referenced - apart of course from its declaration and definition. How is it being added to the routing automatically?
My best guesses are that,

There's a hidden configuration file that I'm not seeing or somehow missed.

The classes are automatically detected somehow but I can't see where this is mentioned explicitly in the documentation.


I've checked the ASP.NET Core documentation and guides and I can't find any mention of this. On top of that, since many tutorials are using Visual Studio, the file is created automatically using a Wizard dialog so I'm not sure if there's another file I should also be looking for.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated, even if its to direct me to documentation I missed.

You don't explicitly list controllers. They are picked up automatically using reflection.

@BurnsBA Thank you! I think I understand. As a follow up - If possible - can you point me to any documentation so that I can read up more on this? Like the rules and alternatives methods of setting up controllers? The best I can find is mvc/controllers but it doesn't mention Reflection.

Routing for MVC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0  Routing for Razor pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-8.0  Routing for APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

It's a bit confusing really, but it will take the controller name from the name of the class minus the "Controller" part.  So your example would be reached via yourdomain . com / api / Some ...  If using API style routing, the method it calls usually would depend on the verb.  So [HttpGet] above any method name would run that method if the request were a GET.

See this bit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes

UseEndpoints doesn't need to be called... it has it's own defaults... but it's all configurable... if you really want to dig into all the options, see routing in general: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Thanks @browsermator! I'll take a look
